# enumerating in pseudo random order - version 2

Tags: combinatorics, cryptography

edit 2:

what kind of statistical test do I need to get an idea of the randomness of the order of a list? The list contains all base-4 numbers from 0000 to 3333 exactly once.

---

edit 1:

I've added this as an edit, because it's too long for the comment I think.

I want a function y=f(x) that I can call with a counter x (x = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...). The return value y of the function must be the same for the same x. This is the case if the function returns y=x or if it returns y=x+1 or if it returns y=x+2 and so on. But it is also the case if y = arr[x] in which x is the index of an array that contains no duplicates. For example the array contains random values that are filtered for duplicates. Filtering however takes O(n^2) time. On the other hand returning y=x+1 is very fast, but then y is certain to look like x for all x. So my question is, can a function be made in which y does not look like x, but that takes less than O(n^2) time and does not use n storage space? From what I've created I'm tempting to believe that it can. But I would rather know who has done this before, because I'm not able to prove my concept except by exhaustive testing and therefore I don't want to use it in my code.

---

original:

My question is "is there a function that can do the same as the first tree lines in the code below, without creating an array of 1000 items?".

I don't want to create an array, because the array must be stored and searched each time I change the upper bound.

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 1) { arr.push(i); }
arr.scramble();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 1) { console.log(arr[i]); }
```

(the above is in base 10, what follows is in base 4)

I came up with an answer that seemed to work somewhat ([enumerating in pseudo random order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639656/enumerating-in-pseudo-random-order)), but not completely. However, today it seems that it does work, but that I did not test it properly.

I created a new piece of code as a jsfiddle. Press the button for a random matrix.

**http://jsfiddle.net/2T7Tc/**

I use a 4x4 matrix, each row can be in any of 24 states. The total number of matrices is therefore 24^4. The initial state of the matrix determines the sequence in which the 256 possible values of a base-4 number are listed.

I tested all 24^4 matrices and after sorting the sequence I got back my original counter, meaning that each item in the sequence is generated exactly once.

Is there a name for this thing? I would like to know if it has been proven to be correct, so I can use it in my code.

I realise that I can only create 24^4 sequences, while the number of possible sequences is 255*254*253*252*...

Comment: It seems that you want an array containing the numbers from 1 to 1000, in random order, but without storing the array.  This does not make sense; please clarify.

Comment: I do not want an array. I want a function y = f(x) such that y does not look like x. This can be done with picking an item from a scrambled array with unique items. This works for as long as the upper bound of the array is not reached. Therefore, what I'm trying to do is not use an array. The arrays that I use are for testing purposes only (except for the matrix). I feel that I need the name for what this is called, I refuse to believe that this has not been solved already, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Please clarify the properties you want of your function.  This question, like your previous ones, is very vague.

Comment: I've made an edit. I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Alas, it does not.  What is the desired domain of your function, what is the desired range, and what do you mean by "does not look like"?  Do you need your function to be one-to-one?  Do you need it to be onto? Do you just need $x$ to be different from $f(x)$, or do you also need $f(x)$ to be different from $f(x+1)$?

Comment: Modular exponentiation seems to do mostly what you want. Pick a prime $p$, a primitive root $g \mod p$, then take the function $x \mapsto y = g^x \pmod p$. As $x$ ranges through $1,\dots,p-1$, so will $y$. Also, except for very small $x$, it is difficult to recover $x$ knowing only $g$ and $y$, this may or may not be what you mean by "does not look like".

Comment: @fkraiem The initial range seems a bit predictable and it's a bit hard to calculate if x gets larger. But this is the kind of function I'm looking for.

Comment: It is not at all hard to calculate. (It takes about $O(\log x)$.)

Comment: @vadim123 I've added a new question regarding "does not look like". I have no means to quantify that.

Comment: I need to write the function because it's not standard in JavaScript and I've read they can take up to a minute for 2000 bit words.